# How to identify if IEditableObject is in edit status?

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services

When implement IEditableObject for an entity in wcf ria service, how can I know if the entity in Edit status(for example, Begin() is starting)?

Comment: will this MSDN link help you out..? if not can you paste what code you have so that we can attempt to help you..? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.entity(v=VS.91).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEditableObject` implements only 3 methods (`BeginEdit`, `CancelEdit` and `EndEdit`), so it will be impossible to detect whether the object is in edit mode, without a custom implementation.

You can for instance, implement an `IsInEdit` property, which you set to true in `BeginEdit` and false in `CancelEdit` and `EndEdit`.